# разница в throw, throw new, throw ex

Tags: c#, .net, исключения, try-catch

В чем все таки разница и зачем вообще бросать исключение?
Я так понимаю если у нас в где-то вызывается метод в котором потенциально может быть ошибка мы должны от туда "бросать" исключение в место от куда метод не посредственно вызывается,

Comment: Вы можете бросить исключение "откуда то", но не можете бросить его "куда то". То есть, например, если между местом, где исключение возникло, и местом, где оно должно быть перехвачено, стоит логгер, который хочет это исключение записать в лог, то он должен его перехватить, записать в лог, и в неизменном виде отправить дальше. Отправка дальше и есть бросание исключения.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если совсем упрощать, то есть всего две конструкции, `throw e` и `throw`.

Первая - `throw e` - берет объект исключения и бросает его. Этот объект поймает первый соответствующий catch выше по стеку. В момент бросания к исключению привязывается стек вызовов, от того места, где был вызван `throw e` и выше. Поймав этот `e` выше, вы можете узнать точное место, где был вызван `throw e`.

Вторая - `throw` - может использоваться только в `catch`, и она пробрасывает пойманное этим `catch` исключение выше так, как будто вы его не поймали.

Простой пример

```
private static void B()
{
    throw new Exception();
}

private static void A()
{
    try
    {
        B();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        A();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

Метод A ловит исключение, но делает вид что не поймал (вызывает `throw`). Поэтому на консоль выводится

```
System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
   at ConsoleApp13.Program.B() in ...
   at ConsoleApp13.Program.A() in ...
   at ConsoleApp13.Program.Main(String[] args) in ...
```

Если же метод A переписать как

```
private static void A()
{
    try
    {
        B();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

То информация о том, что исключение было создано и брошено в B, потеряется:

```
System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
   at ConsoleApp13.Program.A() in 
   at ConsoleApp13.Program.Main(String[] args) in
```

То поведение будет таким же, как если бы в A было написано просто throw `new Exception();`